# How is name(.GlobalEnv) ordered?

Tags: r, names

The documentation of `names` says the following:

> For an environment env, names(env) gives the names of the corresponding list, i.e., names(as.list(env, all.names = TRUE)) which are also given by ls(env, all.names = TRUE, sorted = FALSE).

I've tried `names(x = .GlobalEnv)`, and indeed those are not sorted alphabetically. My question is how are they ordered?

Consider the following example:

```r
rm(list = ls())
temp <- vector(mode = "list", length = 20)
for (i in 1:20)
{
  assign(x = paste("vec", i, sep = "_"),
         value = rnorm(n = 10))
  temp[[i]] <- names(x = .GlobalEnv)
}
temp_1 <- temp
save(temp_1, file = "try_1.RData")

rm(list = ls())
temp <- vector(mode = "list", length = 20)
for (i in 1:20)
{
  assign(x = paste("vec", i, sep = "_"),
         value = rnorm(n = 10))
  temp[[i]] <- names(x = .GlobalEnv)
}
temp_2 <- temp
save(temp_2, file = "try_2.RData")

rm(list = ls())
load(file = "try_1.RData")
load(file = "try_2.RData")
all.equal(target = temp_1, current = temp_2)
#> [1] "Component 18: 21 string mismatches"
#> [2] "Component 19: 22 string mismatches"
#> [3] "Component 20: 23 string mismatches"
temp_1[[20]]
#>  [1] "vec_14"       "vec_15"       "vec_16"       "vec_17"      
#>  [5] "vec_18"       "vec_1"        "vec_19"       "vec_2"       
#>  [9] "vec_3"        "vec_4"        "vec_5"        "vec_6"       
#> [13] "vec_7"        "vec_8"        "vec_20"       "vec_9"       
#> [17] ".Random.seed" "temp"         "i"            "vec_10"      
#> [21] "vec_11"       "vec_12"       "vec_13"
temp_2[[20]]
#>  [1] "i"            "vec_10"       "vec_11"       "vec_12"      
#>  [5] "vec_13"       "vec_14"       "vec_15"       "vec_16"      
#>  [9] "vec_1"        "vec_17"       "vec_2"        "vec_18"      
#> [13] "vec_19"       "vec_3"        "temp"         "vec_4"       
#> [17] "vec_5"        ".Random.seed" "vec_6"        "vec_7"       
#> [21] "vec_8"        "vec_9"        "vec_20"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As it can be seen from above, same ordering of defining the objects doesn't lead to same order in `names(x = .GlobalEnv)`. Are they ordered randomly?

This question is inspired from [this thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/merge-data-frames-in-a-loop/35013).

Comment: If the documentation does not define an order then it would be best not to make use of any order even if such order existed since it could be changed at any time.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: Got it, but I asked this question more out of curiosity than out of need. I run the same code multiple times in R console,and most of the time `all.equal` returns `TRUE`. However, an interesting point is that running this code using `reprex` always showed differences.